# is it possible using Spring Integration as ESB for JSF Projects for integration?

Tags: spring, jsf, integration

I need to integrate some jsf-spring-jpa web applications so I need something like ESB (Spring Integration-Mule) but I didn't find useful sample.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the title of your question is: Yes it is possible

Comment: The questioner wants a full fledged tutorial :)

Comment: I want a full savings account ;-)